# How can I use Card Order?

Tags: hearthstone

In Hearthstone I've noticed that draws always go to my right of the opponents hand, and the cards are never rearranged. Meaning:

1. I can tell whether the opponent played a new card or an old card
2. I can tell how many turns a card has persisted in an opponents hand

Also the coin is always the rightmost card prior to drawing.

Are there any ways I can leverage this information?

Comment: @NBN-Alex I can certainly imply things once I identify their deck genotype.  For example, I can guess what they mulliganed for. They give me even more information if they consider playing a spell but choose not to play it as I can see the arrow, when they're trying to target.

Comment: @Rob I feel that's not a duplicate. My question takes that the opponent's card order is fixed as a given and asks how to exploit that, that question is asking whether the order is fixed.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, this is consistent and you can use that information to help you play.

For example did the player junk their whole hand at mulligan (less likely to have a killer opening), or keep the whole lot?  Did they keep their whole hand but not play it on the first few turns (pieces of a combo maybe)?  Did they consider playing a card then play a different one (might that be a spell if they tried to target something first)?

There are programs like Deck Tracker that will do this for you, giving details like which turn they drew it on, whether it came from another card (like duplicate or a discover card), but it is entirely possible to do it all in your head, if you're good at keeping track of things like that.

It can be very powerful to finesse your choice of play, but it's only a little piece of the puzzle, so you still need to think through your turns and consider all possible plays, but it helps to gauge risk.

Comment: In case anyone is wondering: using the tools like the decktracker will not get you banned. The stance of Blizzard on these kind of programs is, that if it only displays information you could theoretically calculate yourself, they are fine (which is the case with the HS Decktracker).

Answer (score 5):

You can use this to gauge whether or not your opponent has high-curve cards or answers to your threats. If they've been holding something since the beginning of the game, it's likely a late-game threat. If you played a big minion and they removed it with the card they just drew, it's more likely that they were not already holding an answer - perhaps a signal that they may not be able to deal with another big minion.

Comment: That's true, if I'm wailing on my opponent with a big minion and he's holding onto a card, it's not a removal. Likewise if I'm ganging him, he probably isn't holding an AoE card.